# Insert image into textbox with text wrapping in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, layout, microsoft-publisher

Unfortunately, Microsoft has decided to get rid of Publisher, with things like changing pictures no longer working. As a result, I'm trying to make something in Word instead, with little success.

How do I insert images into TextBoxes with text wrapping in Word? I imagine it's probably possible — it's trivially easy in Publisher — but I can't figure out how to do it. Whenever I try, the images are only inserted inline, with other layout options grayed out.

EDIT: As Reddy Lutonadio and harrymc *et al.* have kindly pointed out, this cannot be done in Word. Whoever decided to axe Publisher needs a career change. For now, I'm using Scribus instead.

Comment: You can't. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/wrap-text-and-position-buttons-greyed-out/06d1675d-3711-4556-bc62-4501558ca7a3#:~:text=Pictures%20in%20text%20boxes%20must,to%20In%20Line%20With%20Text.

Comment: Well, drat. Do you know any kludges I could do instead?

Comment: Publisher still exists in Office 365 - I just ran it

Comment: @John - It's not dead yet, but it will be within three years. I'm already looking for an alternative; I use Publisher for putting out a 64-page PDF magazine every two months, and trying to do it in Word would be... I don't think Stack Exchange would approve of that sort of language. I think right now my two best candidates to replace Publisher when Microsoft finally kills it are [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) and [Affinity Publisher](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/publisher/).

Comment: @John You can technically still run it, but Microsoft no longer really supports it; for example, trying to change an image source triggers a 503 server error.

Comment: Possible Publisher alternative: free, open-source, desktop publishing app Scribus, https://www.scribus.net . Haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I still use FrontPage 2003. Microsoft stopped supporting it more than two decades ago. It is running fine on Windows 11 and does what I want.

Comment: @InHocSigno Can you show us an example of the exact layout you are trying to achieve? Word is extremely powerful, so might be some good workarounds.

Comment: @Loeli I ended up just using Scribus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with a Text Box.
An alternative to using the Text Box is to use a single-cell table.

Inside a table cell, images can be inserted with text wrapping.